# I can't load myfile.scala in scala-shell

Tags: scala, scala-shell

I have a Scala file and I want to run it on Scala Shell. I am using the following command:

`load somepath\myfile.scala`

After that console tells me:

> usage: :load -v file

Why my file can't be run?

Comment: what is the full path of the file and is it in same dir where you started scala REPL?

Answer (score 0):

I'm unsure of where exactly you're trying to run the load command, but if you're using it in the Scala REPL, the command is actually ":load *fileName*". Additionally, if you're trying to load a file from any location other than the folder that the file is in, you'll need to use the full file path.

Hope that works,
Connor

Comment: Thanks for the response